# Java finished with non-zero exit value 1 - Android Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

1. Gradle Build : Working fine.
2. Rebuild Project: Working fine.
3. Clean Project: Working Fine.
4. Run: It shows following:

> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value

Detail Error:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers102Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta102Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics210Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComDigitsSdkAndroidDigits180Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer090Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi150Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter180Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore150Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric135Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
>   :app:processDebugResources
>   :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:dexDebug
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
>   The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 12.312 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I have added 3 jar files in my lib folder of "quickblox". I have refereed to all the post related to my problem, but i was not able to successfully build the project. Also i have enable

> multiDexEnabled true

My Build Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled  true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

}


buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}



apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.9.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.3.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: Try to set targetSdkVersion as compileVersion

Comment: @Unii Thank you for your reply. I just now tried to change the targetSdkVersion to complileVersion. Now its showing me "Gradle DSL method not found:  compileVersion()'

Answer (score 0):

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
>   the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
>   it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
>   framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
>   limit.

**From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs** into your app. **For example**, to **include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs**, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0'
```

For more info refer : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

It is similar to instead of using `import.example.pkg1.*` we do `import.example.pkg1.RequiredClass`
**So Include only those play service package you need and check...**
Also check for other libraries as well...whether they contain Classes with same name or not then in that case you will do work around with one library

Comment: Hi @Shadow Droid  i tried changing the build gradle, i am using pushnotification services in the application. But nothing helped. Can you tell me specifically, which are the packages for the google push notification. ?

Comment: you can check in the link for Google Cloud Messaging it is com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0

Comment: Currently its the same only. that is "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0" @Shadow Droid.

Comment: But in question I saw compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' based on that I gave my answer

Comment: Sorry @Shadow Droid, my bad, but after changing it from 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' to "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0' the error still stays the same.

Comment: @Deep Rathod can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90901/android-gradle-build-compile-issue