# unexpected top-level exception:

Tags: android, exception, indexing, overflow, toplevel

I tried to add Google play store services in my build.gradle file and the sync was successful. Now when I tried to run the application, I am getting following exception in Android Studio:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Prior to adding play service, it was working fine. My build.gradle file looks as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xyz.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'me.neavo:volley:2014.12.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I searched the issue on Google and found that issue states that exceeded the limit of 65,536 methods in dex file

```
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

But my project is not that big enough.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and suggest the approach to resolve it.
Thanks.

Comment: which play service module are using?

Comment: Please check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844287/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1-android-gradle/32844773#32844773

Comment: @Veer3383 I am using location api to get current location using GoogleApiClient.

Comment: @Shadow Droid tried your solution but it didn't help

Comment: then you only need to use this one compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0' you need not enable multidex, try and see.

Comment: @Veer3383 this solution worked like a charm. I preferred your approach as it reduces the overall size of final apk and also, no need to enable multidex and adding an entry in manifest. Thanks. :)

Comment: Another way of saying thanx is accepting the answer ; )

Comment: @GaganSingh I had mentioned the same thing what Veer3383 suggested you only difference in that answer i had mentioned service as per that question. I thought you would be able to figure out. Anyways you got problem resolved great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exceeding your max method count limit of 65K .
One solution for this is by using multidex option in gradle.

Modify your build.gradle as below

```
android {
  ...

  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ...
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

[Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Other solution would be to optimize your methods via proguard, which can be  enabled via

```
minifyEnabled true
```

section.

Plus you can optimize your dependencies to avoid exceeding the 65K method count limit.
Checkout this [site](http://www.methodscount.com/), to get the instructions to install a plugin right into the Android Studio which would display the method count of each dependency in your build.gradle side by side. Taking that in view you can decide which dependency to keep and which one can be replaced with something thats less method hungry.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks.
But still I wonder how my app exceeded max method count limit of 65K, Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @GaganSingh refer to the site link i added at the bottom of my answer. There is an option to install a plugin right into Android Studio. You can use that to find which dependency is the culprit.

Comment: I got it. I think Google Play services have over 65k methods and so after using the play services, I got this error. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: In that case you might wanna start using the segmented modules from google play services . Take a look here : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 3):

Dont include the entire play services dependency,

replace

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

with only modules you are using.

Eg.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

Rerfer [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for your refrence,

incase you need to include the play services all modules,

refer to Radix's answer

Answer (score 2):

basically this is caused because you exceed the limits of method.you have two options for solve this error .

1)Decrease the no of methods in your project .Basically the library you added in your projects methods also count in your project methods. so don't use whole package of that library use the module that you uses in your project:For example Google play services you added whole package add the module you want to use like map etc..

2)Second one Enable the multidex for enable multidex :
Now, all you need to do is override this in your Application class:

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

}
```

Add multidex support library in your gradal

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
   <application
   ...
   android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
   ...
  </application>
```

I hope this will Help you....

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Sometimes large library dependencies can also cause symbol size to go up. This link talks about avoiding 65K limit, by means like proguard.

or you can simply employ multidexing, which will create 2 classes.dex files for you, upon reaching large symbol size.